# Application installation fails in play store

Tags: google-play-store

When I was trying to install apps from google play store, it downloads and then pops the error,

> "Application installation failed".

I tried numerous ways described in websites and now the error doesn't pop but when downloading is finished, again it starts downloading. And it causes data loss only.

If there's a solution please let me know.

Comment: *"I tried numerous ways described in websites"* - list whatsoever you've tried so that we don't end up suggesting them.

Comment: Clear play store cache data and app data, then restart the device and open play store. Force stop the play store app, play services and restart play store

Comment: I would guess it is a compatibility problem between your phone/android version and the app. However, it is hard to tell without knowing both

Comment: The phone I'm using is Panasonic P66 Mega, Android Version: 5.1 Lollipop.  It occurs for each and every app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android version in your phone is incompatible with the play store version. When we update play store, without updating android version, this error occurs.

Solution:

> go to settings --> Apps --> Downloaded --> Google Play Store --> Uninstall Updates --> Click 'Ok'

When you uninstall updates it will be replaced with the factory version which is compatible with any android version.