# "App not installed" when trying to install APK

Tags: applications, installation, apk, side-loading

I'm trying to install an apk file on my device, and I'm able to press the Install button, but after a few seconds, I keep receiving this error:

> App not installed.

What is the root cause of this issue and how can I fix it?

I know [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android) is related, but that question deals more with the development aspect than the consumer installation aspect of the error.

Comment: [The answer is available in this link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/183297/application-installation-fails-in-play-store)

Comment: Also related: [Application installation fails in play store](/q/183297/16575) // [What's the cause of “Application not installed” error?](/q/35840/16575) // [APK won't install](/q/97975/16575) // … Pointer: We have a nice [search function](/search?q="app+not+installed"+answers%3A1) here at our site (link gives you 28 related questions which have answers).

Comment: @BinaraMedawatta that's not the answer that worked for me. This is a different error.

Comment: @iBug as I replied to the other commenters, all of the linked questions refer to a different error message, which is not the one I'm receiving. Thus, none of those answers are sufficient to answer my question.

Comment: Anyway, could you tell the source of the APK? There's a possibility that the APK is corrupted, etc (as pointed on Izzy's comment). Also, it'd be helpful if you could paste the LogCat when it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself. The issue was that I had another version of the same application I was trying to install already on my device. After deleting it, the installation worked fine.

Comment: I had the same problem. To give more details: I was able to figure this out via `adb logcat` on the computer: the message was "PackageManager: Package com.zulipmobile signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!". Specifically, I had installed the application (Zulip) from F-Droid, and what I was trying to install was the APK released from github. It's a pity that the message shown on Android is just "App not installed" without any other explanation...